# How do i make mysql fail to insert a row when some column is not set?

Tags: mysql, insert, constraints

I'm running into a problem where it is possible to insert a row into a table whithout specifically setting an INT NOT NULL column (defaults to 0 which is invalid for my purposes)

I create the table this way:

```
CREATE TABLE inventorycontrol (
     ID                         INT NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT
    ,nodeID                     INT NOT NULL CHECK (nodeID > 0)
    ,custom1                    VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
    ,custom2                    VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
    ,custom3                    VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
    ,custom4                    VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
    ,articlekey                 VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL 
    ,amount                     INT NOT NULL
    ,orderID                    INT NULL
    ,supplierID                 INT NULL
    ,customerID                 INT NULL
    ,datecreated                DATETIME NOT NULL
    ,expectedcompletion         DATETIME NOT NULL
    ,datecompleted              DATETIME NULL

    ,PRIMARY KEY (articlekey, datecreated)
)
GO

CREATE INDEX ix_InventoryArticle ON inventorycontrol ( articlekey )
GO

CREATE INDEX ix_InventoryArticle_Custom ON inventorycontrol ( nodeID, custom1, custom2, custom3, custom4 )
GO

CREATE INDEX ix_InventoryAmount ON inventorycontrol ( amount ) 
GO

CREATE INDEX ix_InventoryCreated ON inventorycontrol ( datecreated )
GO

CREATE INDEX ix_InventoryCompleted  ON inventorycontrol ( datecompleted )
GO

ALTER TABLE inventorycontrol
    ADD FOREIGN KEY fk_nodeID (nodeID) REFERENCES node(ID)
GO
```

I would expect this insert to fail:

```
INSERT INTO inventorycontrol ( articlekey, amount, datecreated, expectedcompletion, datecompleted )
VALUES
     ( 'abc', -10, '2009-01-27', '2009-01-27', NULL ) 
GO
```

Unfortunately, this just works. (there is no node WHERE ID=0)

Is there any way i can force this insert to fail short of creating a trigger for inserts?

Thanks in advance,

Kris

P.S. i am using mysql Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.45, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put MySQL into [**strict mode**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_all_tables)

In your configuration file:

```
sql-mode="STRICT_ALL_TABLES"
```

EDIT:

You can also set it locally (and put it back) using this query:

```
SET @mode = @@SESSION.sql_mode;
SET sql_mode = "STRICT_ALL_TABLES";

INSERT...;

SET sql_mode = @mode;
```

Comment: That looks good but is not an option, there are many databases on the server and we cannot risk breaking anything else.

Comment: The edit seems good, but unfortunately I will probably not be the guy doing the actual INSERTs. I am reading up on the concept, perhaps I can rewrite the specifications to allow for triggers. (triggers are problematic to copy from db to db)

Comment: I think if you can't change the SQL or the server configuration then triggers are all that's left

Answer (score -1):

Set the values NOT NULL, if this dont work and you cant check the values by code before inserting the row you should put new triggers that looks for values when there is an insert or a modify call on your database.

hope this helps!

Comment: It is set NOT NULL and there is even a check constraint that should make it not be 0 as well (doesn't seem to work though)